# Carrierwave upload to ftp

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ftp, carrierwave

I've been searching for a while for a gem that allow me to set storage type as :ftp.

How do you usually solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might be a little late but, try this gem out:

https://github.com/luan/carrierwave-ftp